# What is "private" target in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

Could someone help me find some reference to the *private* target in [this code](https://github.com/NVIDIA/libnvidia-container/blob/master/mk/docker.mk#L116-L119)? Also, how can I use it?

More specifically, how do you interpret these targets that start with `--`.

```
# private OS targets with defaults
--ubuntu%: OS := ubuntu
--debian%: OS := debian
--amazonlinux%: OS := amazonlinux
```

Comment: While this obviously has a lot of potentially-relevant context, please try to include the relevant code of the Makefile! Making the link static (including commitsha) may be a good intermediate to help other users reading your Question in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a Make feature, but rather a convention they use. They seem to prefix all targets that are not intended for public use with `--`.

Comment: I was suspecting that...but it is really difficult to understand what they are trying to do...any idea?

Comment: The specific lines you linked to set target-specific variables based on target name prefixes. E.g. `--ubuntu%: OS := ubuntu` sets variable `OS` to `ubuntu` for all targets with names prefixed with `--ubuntu`.